# how to mix data.append with $this.attr()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I just wanted to learn how to mix data.append() with $this.attr() in jquery ajax.Because i have forms created inside php while loop and each form has its unique name. i have this:

```
var data = new FormData()
    data.append( 'photo', $( '#photo_' + $this.attr("name") + '_id' )[0].files[0] ), 
    data.append( 'firstname', $( '#firstname_' + $this.attr("name") + '_id' ).val()),
    data.append( 'lastname', $( '#lastname_' + $this.attr("name") + '_id' ).val()),
    data.append( 'fathername', $( '#fathername_' + $this.attr("name") + '_id' ).val()),
    data.append( 'nationalID', $( '#nationalID_' + $this.attr("name") + '_id' ).val()),
    data.append( 'month', $( '#month_' + $this.attr("name") + '_id' ).val()),
    data.append( 'year', $( '#year_' + $this.attr("name") + '_id' ).val()),
    data.append( 'day', $( '#day_' + $this.attr("name") + '_id' ).val()),
    data.append( 'class', $( '#class_' + $this.attr("name") + '_id' ).val()),
    data.append( 'identity', $this.attr("name").val());
$.ajax({
        type         : 'POST',
        url          : 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/process/edit-student-process.php',
        processData  : false,
        contentType  : false,
        data         : data,
        enctype      : 'multipart/form-data',
        dataType     : 'json',
    })
```

but with this code, ajax redirects to the php file that is supposed to process form and not stays on form. where is the problem?

and a part of my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal edit_student" name="<?php echo $student['user_ID']; ?>" action="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/danesh-sanat/process/edit-student-process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="firstname_<?php echo $student['user_ID']; ?>_id" id="firstname_<?php echo $student['user_ID']; ?>_id" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $student['user_firstname']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="lastname_<?php echo $student['user_ID']; ?>_id" id="lastname_<?php echo $student['user_ID']; ?>_id" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $student['user_lastname']; ?>">
```

Comment: if you have a redirect, it comes not from FormData. show us the function where the AJAX call is made

Comment: try with async:false

Comment: not working. I have another ajax just like this one but the difference is that that one has not $this.attr("name") inside data.append() and that works fine. is that the problem?

Comment: What is `$this`? Are you preventing `form` to be submited? Your question is missing some context

Comment: @dom async false is deprecated and should never be used anyway

Comment: A. Wolf. $this comes from "$this = $(this)" and it's the form that is being processes. anyway i solved the problem by defining $this.attr("name") outside and putting the variable instead.